# Proper way of using adverb

Tags: grammar, adverbs, adverb-placement

I know the first one is correct, but what about the second one? Would that be still?

> 1. I could **hardly** hear her voice.
> 2. I could hear her voice **hardly**.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is not correct. ***hardly*** is an adverb with particular use when it comes to word order. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/hardly) says

> We usually put ***hardly*** **in mid position**, **between the subject
> and the main verb**, *or after the modal verb or first auxiliary verb,
> or after main verb **be***:
>
> My piano lesson is on Monday, and I’ve hardly played it this week.
>
> I can hardly wait.
>
> There were hardly any tourists.
>
> When hardly is modifying either the main verb or the following noun,
> we can put it directly before the verb or before the noun phrase:
>
> She hardly had any sleep. or She had hardly any sleep.
>
> In more formal styles, to refer to something happening immediately
> after something else, we use ***hardly … when***. We move *hardly* to front
> position and invert the subject and verb:
>
> ***Hardly had I arrived there when*** I was called back to the head office 100 miles
> away. (I arrived there and then I was immediately called back.)

There are adverbs which could be used in the position you gave ***hardly*** in your second sentence though:

> I could hear her voice ***clearly/constantly/vaguely***.

Answer (score 0):

"hardly hear" would be the typical expression. The second sentence looks wrong. 
The placement of adverbs varies, and they can often appear at the beginning or end of a sentence.  However, sometimes the adverb is expected to be right next to the verb, in a similar way to an adjective which is placed right before a noun. Such is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

- I could hardly hear her voice.
  or
- I hardly could hear her voice.

The first is the most used.

Putting an adverb like hardly at the end is a mistake.